# Funcionamento do @Transactional do Spring Framework

Tags: spring, transações, annotation

1 - Na documentação do Spring é descrito o uso de `@Transactional` do Spring nas classes de regra de negócio(`ProdutosService` por exemplo) tem algum motivo especial para se usar essa anotação nessas classes ao invés de utilizar nas DAO's?

2 - O funcionamento da anotação `@Transactional` e a mesma do uso do padrão [Open Session in View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView)? Senão, em quais situações é mais interessante usar um ao invés do outro?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A anotação `@Transactional` demarca transações (você pode iniciar transações aninhadas, propagar transações para outras camadas, etc). A transação é uma unidade de trabalho isolada que leva o banco de dados de um estado consistente a outro estado consistente. Pense em termos de transações de negócio mesmo.

A recomendação por não demarcar a camada de DAO e sim a camada de negócios é devido a própria natureza e granularidade de operações de cada camada. Operações da camada DAO geralmente possuem granularidade fina (insira algo, atualize algo, consulte algo, etc). Já a camada de negócio é de granularidade mais grossa, e pode agrupar várias operações da camada DAO (bem como de outras camadas; e.g., filas JMS).

```
Bean de Negócio
  @Autowired BeanDAO1
  @Autowired BeanDAO2

  @Transactional  
  meu método de negócio() {
     consulta algo do DAO1
     faz um processamento
     insere algo no DAO2
     faz um update no DAO1
  }
```

Veja que métodos de negócio são bons candidatos para "unidades de trabalho" transacionais. A ideia é que a unidade de trabalho que leva o banco de um estado consistente a outro estado consistente execute várias operações. Você quer que uma de duas coisas ocorra:

1. O método de negócios seja executado com sucesso e um *commit* de tudo seja feito
2. Uma exceção qualquer ocorra, nesse caso um *rollback* deverá ser feito para o estado anterior (como se nenhuma das operações tivesse ocorrido).

Agora imagine que você anotou o método de inserção do **DAO2** com `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` (algo que fazia sentido em determinado pedaço da sua aplicação). Caso faça isso o seu método de negócio não vai mais fazer *rollback* do que foi inserido no **DAO2** (já que o *insert* acontece em sua própria transação). Imagine agora que o *update* no **DAO1** falhou e disparou uma exceção; com isso será feito um *rollback* desse *update*, porém o valor inserido pelo **DAO2** no passo anterior será mantido, potencialmente deixando seu banco de dados em um estado inconsistente. Dessa maneira é boa prática fazer com que a camada de DAO seja uma mera "consumidora" de transações, e não uma agente ativa de demarcações.

---

### Open Session in view substitui a demarcação transacional?

**Não**. Ok, fui um tanto quanto categórico aqui; porém a verdade é que se todas as transações da sua aplicação possuem o mesmo escopo da requisição (*transaction-per-request*) esse é um forte indicativo que há algo errado.

O propósito do padrão *Open Session in View* (*OSiV*) é facilitar a vida do programador, permitindo que entidades sejam carregadas de maneira preguiçosa (*lazy*) em tempo de renderização da *view* (evitando `LazyInitializationException` e similares).

```
<!-- Poderia disparar uma exceção se a sessão estivesse fechada -->  
#{minhaEntidade.listaDeOutrasEntidadesLazy}
```

Eu já tive várias discussões sobre o padrão *OSiV*, pessoalmente considero-o um anti-padrão, ou ao menos uma má prática. Enquanto existem vários defensores do padrão, [eu não estou sozinho na lista de dissidentes](http://blog.frankel.ch/the-opensessioninview-antipattern). *OSiV* é certamente útil e poupa tempo do programador evitando que ele tenha que se preocupar em checar se os objetos esperados foram corretamente carregados. Por outro lado abusar desse tipo de técnica  também estimula a proliferação de vários problemas. Descaso com a demarcação transacional é um deles, assim como problemas do tipo `N + 1`consultas.

Digamos por exemplo que o seu provedor JPA tenha que fazer uma consulta para recuperar cada uma das entidades de uma lista *lazy*, isso gerará vários *selects* desnecessários; algo que poderia ter sido facilmente resolvido com um `JOIN FETCH` potencialmente passará indetectado para produção devido ao uso de *OSiV*. No melhor caso *OSiV* age como uma rede de segurança e esconde o problema, no pior caso ele cria um problema ainda maior.

Do ponto de vista arquitetural sessões longas transversais acabam amarrando as camadas: exceções da camadada de dados potencialmente afetam a *view*, podendo acontecer em tempo de renderização. Do ponto de vista de *performance* sessões de longa duração acabam consumindo mais recursos. Do ponto de vista de confiabilidade o padrão acaba abrindo espaço para falhas inesperadas, etc, etc, etc.

De qualquer maneira, como o assunto é polêmico, deixo claro que essa é apenas a minha opinião.

Agora sobre o controle transacional não há muito o que ser discutido; seus métodos de negócio devem ter transações bem demarcadas conforme as regras da sua aplicação. Se eventualmente você quiser utilizar *OSiV* para carregar algo na *view* ok, mas nessa etapa todas as transações de negócio já devem ter sido commitadas. Ou seja, uma coisa são as transações de negócio com operações de escrita potencialmente destrutivas e outra completamente diferente é a sessão que fica aberta na *view* para fins de carregamento tardio de objetos de determinada consulta.

Comment: Obrigado primeiramente por me responder. Para eu entender: a demarcação do métodos é utilizada para definir a natureza de cada método sob uma transação, como, por exemplo, se um método deverá ser executado na transação atual ou será criada uma transação a parte para a execução deste, ou se não deve executar durante uma transação, etc.. Certo? Sobre OSiV, o mais grave que vi no link que você citou foi a quebra da arquitetura em camadas, pois ocorre a preocupação de se abrir transações na camada de apresentação o que conceitualmente é ruim.

Comment: Completando a resposta anterior, o problema N + 1 pode ser resolvido com o `JOIN FETCH`, `BATCH FETCHING` (paginação da coleção de objetos -só não sei se dar para usar JOIN neste-). Sobre um problema citado no texto do link: "...if an exception occurs while fetching the session...", eu acho difícil acontecer este tipo de exceção, só consigo imaginar de isso acontecer por causa de má configuração/programação. Você acha melhor então abrir transações nas classes de regra de negócio? Ou mesmo usar AOP nessas classes?

Comment: Olá Klayton, fico feliz em ajudar. Sobre a demarcação de transações, é isso memso. Em outras palavras, ela define os limites das unidades de trabalho. Você pode propagar a transação atual para os métodos que estão sendo chamados, criar uma transação a parte para determinado método, etc (a ideia é que a transação "envolve o método").

Comment: Sobre o OSiV, não quis dizer que ele é a causa de problemas N + 1 (a causa de problemas N + 1 é má programação como você bem detectou). Meu ponto aqui é que o OSiV "favorece o desleixo", se o programador não ficar atento aos logs pode acabar deixando um problema fácil de resolver escapar para produção. Um colega uma vez me disse que OSiV é a "rede de segurança de programadores inexperientes", eu já penso diferente, prefiro que os programadores gastem um pouco de tempo tratando `LazyInitializationException` e similares do que deixando escapar esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Sobre problemas durante a inicialização de variáveis *lazy* durante a renderização, eles acontecem sim. Imagine um *timeout* ou um valor que foi removido do banco externamente (fora do contexto de persistência). O problema apontado é que nessa altura do campeonato o código já não está mais sobre seu controle, ou seja, você não pode simplesmente dar um `catch` a nível de *controller* e mandar o usuário para uma tela de erro (pois o *controller* já fez sua parte e está fora da jogada). O problema não é tão exótico assim (já vi acontecer).

Comment: Finalmente, EJBs, Proxys ou AOP do Spring, etc não te livram de demarcação transacional. As anotações são o que fazem tudo funcionar. Entre controle transacional declarativo (anotações do Spring ou EJB) vs controle explícito, pessoalmente prefiro a demarcação transacional devido a sua simplicidade.

Comment: Quero deixar claro porém que não estou dizendo para você abandonar o *OSiV* (o artigo menciona inclusive o Gavin King, não estou desdizendo o que ele disse :)); apenas não tenho *OSiV* como uma das minhas práticas favoritas... Passei muito tempo dando manutenção em sistemas que faziam péssimo uso do JPA / JTA / Spring, com demarcação transacional inexistente, consultas horrendas e todo tipo de gambiarra. Por exemplo: telas que disparam centenas de consultas para o banco devido a problemas de N + 1. Hoje, quando posso, uso o bom e velho `JdbcTemplate` (simples é melhor ;)).

Comment: Hmmm entendi sobre o perigo do _OSiV_, ele "oculta" do programador certos problemas que continuam ainda existindo mesmo utilizando o _OSiV_ e a chance de programadores caírem nisso é grande. Sobre o controle de transações, estava pensando numa alternativa ao _OSiV_ (calma, não vou abandoná-lo), e estava pensando em utilizar _AOP_ para iniciar e commitar transações pois como eu entendi aqui, não é só porque eu tenho os métodos demarcados que a transação por mágica iria iniciar e commitar sozinha, eu tenho que explicitamente definir quando iniciar e commitar certo? Ou eu viajei?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15970/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-klaytonbrito).