# Configurar applicationContext do Spring aproveitando outros arquivos de configuração

Tags: hibernate, spring, glassfish, configuração

Tenho o seguinte `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <!-- Configuração para a instância do SessionFactory -->
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Propriedades para o Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">
            com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
            thread
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.generator_mappings">
            true
        </property>

        <!-- Propriedades para o Pool de Conexões HirakiCP -->
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">
            com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste-database1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">
            admin123
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">
            10
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">
            30000
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">
            250
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">
            2048
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useLocalSessionState">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useLocalTransactionState">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.maintainTimeStats">
            false
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useUnbufferedInput">
            false
        </property>

        <!-- Mapeamento de classes -->
        <!-- <mapping package="org.sgct.model" /> -->
        <mapping class="org.teste.model.Usuario" />
        <mapping class="org.teste.model.Contato" />
        <mapping class="org.teste.model.Endereco" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

> Dúvidas

1 - No arquivo de configuração do Spring (applicationContext.xml por exemplo) ao invés de ter que digitar cada propriedade neste arquivo, é possível aproveitar configurações do arquivo `hibernate.cfg.xml`utilizando o seguinte trecho código:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath*:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

Mas não sei que propriedades ele aproveita do arquivo `hibernate.cfg.xml` quando se utiliza este trecho de código. O que eu quero entender quais propriedades ele aproveita (como talvez trechos de mapeamento de classes) além da propriedades básicas(dialect, providade_class, etc.) para que eu possa complementar o trecho com propriedades que ele não utiliza.

2 - Quando configurado o pool de conexões (no meu caso estou utilizando o HikariCP) há forma parecida de aproveitar a configuração de outro arquivo como no trecho de configuração do hibernate que eu apresentei na questão anterior?

3 - Pretendo utilizar JNDI em um arquivo xml (no caso do Tomcat era o arquivo `context.xml`) porque além do Hibernate eu utilizarei o Spring Security, mas como utilizo o Glassfish eu não sei se [esta configuração que está no repositório do projeto HirakiCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-%28Tomcat,-etc.%29) irá funcionar da mesma forma no Glassfish pelo fato de ser para Tomcat. Não sei também se toda ou parte da configuração do pool de conexão irá para o arquivo de configuração do JNDI.

4 - Há também o caso de referenciar a conexão no trecho de configuração do Hibernate pois como no na minha versão do `hibernate.cfg.xml` que coloquei acima eu utilizo a propriedade `hibernate.connection.provider_class` mas [neste artigo](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring) é utilizado a propriedade `dataSource`. Qual a diferença entre a utilização de um ou outro? Quando utilizado JNDI é utilizado qual destes?

Comment: Uma recomendação, mesmo sabendo que as perguntas estão relacionadas, dentro do possível tente quebrar suas dúvidas em múltiplas questões (isso não só ajuda o catálogo do site, mas aumenta suas chances, pois pode ser que um usuário seja capaz de responder uma mas não todas as questões).

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado Anthony.

Comment: Sem problemas, eu escrevi a resposta enquanto você estava editando, não percebi que você tinha subdivido. Se quiser fazer *rollback* não tem problema, o conselho foi mais para te ajudar a obter respostas (se quiser deixar subdivido eu "refatoro" aqui também).

Comment: Não precisa mais, mas valeu. Eu estava subdividindo as questões, mas como você colocou uma resposta eu voltei do jeito que estava para não complicar. Mas na próximas questões já sei como fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### TL;DR:
>
> - Use o que puder / quiser do seu servidor de aplicação
> - Quanto mais componentes do Servidor de Aplicação usar, mais simples ficará sua configuração.
> - Você não precisa repetir configurações.
> - Praticamente tudo que é configurável do `hibernate.cfg.xml` pode ser configurado no Spring; mantenha a configuração no local que fizer mais sentido e onde possa ser melhor reaproveitado (e.g., um *data source* configurado no Spring poderá ser usado com um `JdbcTemplate`).

Segue um apanhado sobre suas dúvidas:

1. Enquanto o [Javadoc da classe](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) não é claro sobre quais recursos são aproveitados, veja que existem propriedades extras para carregar arquivos de mapeamento (`setMappingDirectoryLocations`, `setMappingJarLocations`, `setMappingLocations`, `setMappingResources`). O Spring irá reaproveitar a configuração de *data source*, transações, etc, mas você não precisa configurar nada disso no `hibernate.cfg.xml` (se quiser, pode configurar tudo pelo Spring vide 3).
2. Sim. Veja três:
3. No GlassFish você irá configurar um *pool* de conexões no próprio console (que será persistido no arquivo `domain.xml`, mas isso não vem ao caso). Use o *pool* do próprio GlassFish, não se preocupe em integrar um *pool* externo. Adicionalmente você não precisaria nem configurar e utilizar o Hibernate se não quiser. O GlassFish já vem com o EclipseLink, basta você criar um arquivo `persistence.xml` que ele já se encarregará de disponibilizar as bibliotecas para você (essa é a principal vantagem de um *App Server* vs um *container* como o Tomcat). É claro que você é livre para configurar e utilizar o Hibernate e usufruir de sua API se quiser. No Spring há pouco a ser feito uma vez que o *container* vai cuidar do *pool* e de transações:

   ```
   <!-- Obtém data source do GlassFish -->
   <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasSource" 
        jndi-name="jdbc/dataSourceName" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
   <!-- Detecta e configura o provedor de transações do GlassFish -->
   <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
   ```

   E então suas configurações do [`LocalSessionFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) ou - se preferir o caminho do JPA puro - use o [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) (veja [esse artigo](http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/15/using-jpa-and-jta-with-spring/) para maiores detalhes). Ambos consomem o `dataSource` e o `transactionManager`.

   - No caso do Hibernate, você pode tanto pular a configuração de *data source* para que ele use a do `hibernate.cfg.xml` quanto excluir essa configuração do `hibernate.cfg.xml` e configurar tudo pelo Spring; você também pode escolher entre configurações com ou sem JTA (já que o GlassFish provê o serviço, não custa nada). Para mais detalhes veja os métodos [`setDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-) e [`setJtaTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setJtaTransactionManager-java.lang.Object-)
   - Analogamente para JPA você pode também pular a configuração de *data source* para que o Spring use o que foi específicado no `persistence.xml`, ou adotar a estratégia oposta e excluir a configuração relativa a isso do `persistence.xml`, configurando apenas pelo Spring (para mais detalhes veja os métodos [`setDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-) e [`setJtaDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setJtaDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-).
4. Essa é apenas uma propriedade do Hibernate, se você usar o *data source* do *connection pool* do GlassFish não precisará se preocupar com isso. Imaginando que você queira usar um *pool* externo e não queira configurar essa propriedade diretamente no `hibernate.cfg.xml`é possível também configurá-lo pelo Spring:

   - Configuração por anotações / java (vide [exemplo do artigo mencionado](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring)):

     ```
     Properties hibernateProperties() {
         return new Properties() {
             {
                 // Demais propriedades
                 setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", env.getProperty("com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"));
             }
         };
     }
     ```
   - Configuração  xml:

     ```
     <bean id="sessionFactory"
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
         <property name="configLocation" value="classpath*:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
             <property name="hibernateProperties">
             <props>
                 <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" 
                     value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider" />
             </props>
     </bean>
     ```

Comment: Obrigado por me responder Anthony. Quando se projeta um aplicação usando apenas MySQL por exemplo, é interessante ainda usar o JTA? Pois pelo que li sobre o JTA, JTA só é interessante quando se usa vários recursos externos (e não só um, no caso do MySQL), o que você acha?

Comment: Olá Klayton, você realmente não precisa de transações distribuídas se só tem um banco; porém precisa de um `TransactionManager` para as transações declarativas do Spring (vide [sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26503/funcionamento-do-transactional-do-spring-framework/26527#26527)). Enquanto você pode usar um [HibernateTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html) (modelo *session per thread*),se você já tem um *container* provendo o serviço de JTA, por que não usar?

Comment: Veja que, após setado, você programará da mesma maneira que faria com um `TransactionManager` mais simples, a diferença é que poderá incluir um segundo *data source*, fila jms, etc sem problemas, e estará usando os compoenentes do *App Server*.

Comment: Eu estava olhando a documentação do MySQL e do Glassfish e fiz um pool de conexão, até que não é difícil, a pelo que eu entendi o controle de transações é implicitamente ativo quando se cria um pool de conexões no Glassfish (servidores de aplicação é praticamente novo para mim, desde que eu só usava Tomcat). A minha dúvida é que só usando a tag `<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>` (com o datasource configurado claro) é o suficiente para que o controle de transações do Glassfish seja usado, tipo, não preciso criar um `bean` de um `HibernateTransactionManager` (no caso de uso do Hibernate) certo?

Comment: Opa, a ideia é ser simples ;). O `tx:jta-transaction-manager` irá detectar o *container* e configurar um *bean* `JtaTransactionManager` (com nome `transactionManager`). Faz muito tempo que não uso Hibernate puro, mas acho que se você  configurar o `LocalSessionFactoryBean` para usar esse *bean* (usando a propriedade `jtaTransactionManager`) tudo deve funcionar como esperado. Se preferir fazer tudo do lado do hibernate precisará configurar o `jta-data-source`, bem omo como as propriedades `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` e `hibernate.transaction.factory_class`

Comment: Entendi. O Spring facilita a configuração. E sobre as propriedades que você citou, `jta-data-source` não é um propriedade do Hibernate (acho que você quis dizer para configurar as propriedades sobre transações do Hibernate), a propriedade `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` pelo que eu li na documentação a configuração default dela deve bastar, o valor do `hibernate.transaction.factory_class` seria o `org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory` para quando se usa JTA certo?

Comment: Opa, perdão, encurtei meu comentário sobre JTA e acabei deixando escapar (o `jta-data-source` é do JPA). A propriedade que quis dizer é `hibernate.connection.datasource`. Sobre a `factory_class` acredito que tenha que ser `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory` (para deixar o *container* controlar as transações, veja [essa melhoria](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9480)), e a `jta.platform` do GlassFish, por motivos históricos, é a `org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform`. O Spring já configura tudo isso para você.

Comment: Ata, entendi, sem problemas. Sobre esta melhoria do `CMTTransactionFactory` é interessante, Hibernate tinha essa funcionalidade mas não funcionava corretamente, a melhoria garante que se faça um `flush()` de inserções e atualizações antes de qualquer query pendente.