# Porque o spring data persiste a informação quando eu utilizo um set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Tenho um metodo mais ou menos como o seguinte dentro de uma service:

```java
@Transactional
public void atualizarPosicoes(Integer novaPosicao, Long idTarefaAtualizada){
    this.repositorio.listAllTarefas().forEach((Tarefa tarefa) -> {
        if(tarefa.getId().equals(idTarefaAtualizada)){
            tarefa.setPosicao(novaPosicao);
        }
    });
}
```

Vejam que em nenhum momento eu executo um `this.repositorio.save(tarefa)` porém ao final da execução do meu metodo a minha tarefa no DB está atualizada. Já tentei utilizar o `.stream()` porém o resultado é o mesmo, no meu caso em específico esse é o comportamento esperado, porém fiquei com a duvida, porque ele persiste mesmo sem eu executar o `.save()`?

Comment: Interessante, mas você tem certeza de que não manipulou o objeto antes? Realizou alguma atualização nele antes deste método?

Comment: Sim, o metodo so faz isso mesmo, busca do repositorio e da um set, mas a resposta do Lucas Miranda esclareceu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja devido a sua anotação `@Transactional`, ele abre a transação no começo e caso tudo dê certo ele realiza o commit no final, tem uma explicação bem interessante sobre essa anotação aqui:

[Funcionamento do @Transactional do Spring Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26503/funcionamento-do-transactional-do-spring-framework)

Comment: Muito bom, esclareceu :)